# Should people put bounties on other people's questions more often?

Tags: discussion, bounty, privileges

If you look at the bounties tab, you see all of the questions that people want answered. However, should we be encouraging people to put bounties on other people's questions more often? Many people have good questions but are new contributors, so they do not have enough reputation to create bounties. Bounties are "a reputation reward you can put on a question to get it more attention for exactly one week." Most of the bounties placed currently are by the creator of the question. Should other people be placing more bounties?

Comment: If people want to, they can. If they don't want to, they don't have to. That's the right amount.

Comment: People who have *asked* the question have the most interest invested in said question, it's therefore not surprising that the majority of bounties are from the author.

Comment: The second largest group is likely third parties who have an interest in the question (such as after running into the same problem). Bounties for other reasons than that are rare at best

Comment: "Many people have good questions but are new contributors" -- huh? What tags do you frequent?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, people who put bounties on other people's questions would be someone who has the same question, and wants the answer badly enough that they are willing to offer a bounty. This provides an incentive to askers to make their question as useful to others as possible, not only to attract upvotes, but also increases the chance that someone else will bounty their question if they have not gotten an answer.

Bounties from someone who is not the question author is a signal that the question was so helpful to someone else that they were willing to spend their reputation to offer a bounty. Encouraging offering bounties on mediocre questions would dilute this.